# Converting MP3 Duration to Megabytes

Tags: math, mp3

If I have an MP3 that has a duration of 3:02 with a bitrate of 192kbps is it possible to get an approximate, or exact, size of the file programatically?

So, taking the 192kbps and multiplying by 182 seconds (3:02) gives

```
192 x 182 = 34944
```

Convert that to megabytes and you get `4.26562`

In PHP:

```
($this->duration * $this->bitrate) / 8192;
```

Is it safe to assume that the approximate filesize of the given MP3 would be 4.2 megabytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're absolutely right. I even found a forum with a similar discussion ending with the same conclusion. It contains interesting examples : http://www.wjunction.com/5-general-discussion/80348-calculate-mp3-time-length-bitrate-file-size.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, excluding the [metadata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3). Unless it includes lyrics and a thumbnail, the base estimate should be accurate.